# Order of name and title in references of CV

Tags: citations, application, cv, titles, personal-name

Since the references in a CV includes a few names of people and their titles, I would like to put them in an alphabet order. Note that in my country, family names are always put first, for example: Prof. Nguyen Van An, then "Nguyen" is the family name. So can I put names in the following way:

1. Nguyen, Van An, Prof.
   University of XYZ
2. Smith, John, Prof.
   University of ABC

Comment: It seems maybe your question is about inverting the order within names and not others, such that the family name is first for all: writing John Smith as Smith, John, but Nguyen Van An as Nguyen Van An. Is this correct? It seems this is not quite the same as the title question about alphabetical order, as in your example these are not in alphabetical order.

Comment: Thanks, it is correct, I have just changed them in an alphabet order.

Comment: Prof Ngyyen Van An then Prof John Smith somewhat respects the order. I think that none of the involved people care as much as you, to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest either going for an international format as <Title/s> or as you mentioned is the format in your country <Title+first name+middle name> since it makes it easier to read.

You can find [this post](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/388996/349171) helpful which states that if there is a convention you need to follow then you can do that.